# How do I upload a file into an Amazon S3 signed url with python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, pre-signed-url

I have managed to generate an Amazon S3 Signed URL with boto3.

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration=3600):
    """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param object_name: string
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid - 1 hour in this case
    :return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
    """

    # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': object_name}, ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None

    # The response contains the presigned URL
    return response

result = create_presigned_url("bucket123", "test.txt")
```

assuming bucket123 exists.
This code returns me a URL like this:

```
https://bucket123.s3.amazonaws.com/test.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA56EZ34KPFKO5366J&Signature=7aAZXXDwtvKGLaeu1ATHRJuaFCs%3D&Expires=1635117707
```

My question is:

Using python and boto3, is it possible to upload a file in this pre-signed url?
How do I go on about this?

Comment: If you have boto3 then you would not use a pre-signed URL to upload a file to S3. You would simply use the boto3 methods, such as put_object and upload_file.

Comment: @jarmod While I agree with you, ... I need to be able to provide a pre-signed URL in this case. How would you suggest I get a URL that looks like this back? 
`https://bekim-cribl1.s3.amazonaws.com/test.tgz?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA56EZ34KPFKO5367J&Signature=MUUJWwA%2B9V5d7H7DjeorLYsSguo%3d&Expires=1635111412`

Comment: @Marcin Thank you so much for the help with this .. Ideally I would like to have the URL generated back in the fashion of : `https://bekim-cribl1.s3.amazonaws.com/test.tgz?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA56EZ34KPFKO5367J&Signature=MUUJWwA%2B9V5d7H7DjeorLYsSguo%3d&Expires=1635111412`
Any  idea on how can I achieve that?

Comment: Why do you want the pre-signed URL to look a certain way (which appears to be sigv2)? The currently-supported signing method is signature v4. Earlier signing methods are in an extended period of deprecation.

Comment: @jarmod You make a good point. Pardon me for asking just like this, but, How do I obtain a Signature v4 type of URL?

Comment: All current SDKs and the awscli will generate v4 signed URLs, by default.

Comment: you can specifiy a configuration for the client. Below, it explicitly sets the signature version to 's3v4'. This version of the signature is used in the AWS Signature Version 4 signing process, which is the latest signing version for S3. 


self.s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=key_id, aws_secret_access_key=key_secret, config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'), region_name='eu-west-2', endpoint_url='https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you have the pre-signed url, you don't need boto3 at all. Instead you can use regular python functions for uploading files to S3. For example using python's [requests](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/requests/requests_file_upload.htm). Also you should be using [generate_presigned_post](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html#generating-a-presigned-url-to-upload-a-file)

```
def create_presigned_post(bucket_name, object_name,
                          fields=None, conditions=None, expiration=3600):
    """Generate a presigned URL S3 POST request to upload a file

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param object_name: string
    :param fields: Dictionary of prefilled form fields
    :param conditions: List of conditions to include in the policy
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid
    :return: Dictionary with the following keys:
        url: URL to post to
        fields: Dictionary of form fields and values to submit with the POST
    :return: None if error.
    """

    # Generate a presigned S3 POST URL
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(bucket_name,
                                                     object_name,
                                                     Fields=fields,
                                                     Conditions=conditions,
                                                     ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None

    # The response contains the presigned URL and required fields
    return response

result = create_presigned_post("bucket123", "test.txt")



import requests    # To install: pip install requests

# Generate a presigned S3 POST URL
object_name = 'test.txt'
result = create_presigned_post("marcin3", object_name)

# Demonstrate how another Python program can use the presigned URL to upload a file
with open(object_name, 'rb') as f:
    files = {'file': (object_name, f)}
    http_response = requests.post(result['url'], data=result['fields'], files=files)
# If successful, returns HTTP status code 204
logging.info(f'File upload HTTP status code: {http_response.status_code}')
```

Comment: Gettting error:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIA56EZ34KPFKO53663</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>POST

multipart/form-data; boundary=f9cd89cc9f8848cb3c648bb60896faae
1635120065
/bucket123/test.txt</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>tCJ1oWjPRcRs3vaP64KzxFgn1z4=</SignatureProvided>
`
@Marcin

Comment: error continued:
`<StringToSignBytes>50 4f 53 54 0a 0a 6d 75 6c 74 69 70 61 72 74 2f 66 6f 72 6d 2d 64 61 74 61 3b 20 62 6f 75 6e 64 61 72 79 3d 66 39 63 64 38 39 63 63 39 66 38 38 34 38 63 62 33 63 36 34 38 62 62 36 30 38 39 36 66 61 61 65 0a 31 36 33 35 31 32 30 30 36 35 0a 2f 62 65 6b 69 6d 2d 63 72 69 62 6c 31 2f 74 65 73 74 2e 74 78 74</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>3D8J1523P6FS7TBV</RequestId><HostId>tnERzMP+wJsbPQcSpxiVhhdWuXFSmWkZDK+qkBKycd3ilLFHJa5FrrwBuwhfe7lz09e3vgX+Tkm=</HostId></Error>`

Comment: @Becks How did it go? The error persists?

Comment: The file finally uploads fine with the create_presigned_post() method. Two final remarks. I don't see the pre-signed URL printed anymore AND When I go to access the file in the S3 console, I get
`<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>CQNCGDS4YKCPDWQ6</RequestId>
<HostId>
LsJI1jBMUCeQpL4qjfqipmvYeCJ5TaS3ZoBwbmXMbbklWo5stWMdVtGI50Ib+XDciHerIm5AADw=
</HostId>
</Error>`

Comment: ^^ - Tagging you for visibility

Comment: Accepted!!! - Thank you !!!

Comment: @Macin : I asked the access denied part here:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/69718314/779429

Comment: Hi @David How did you resolve the signature error? I created a presinged url to upload but when I try it with Postman i get a signature error