# S3 File Access Denied when uploaded with pre-signed url boto3 call create_presigned_post()

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, access-denied, pre-signed-url

I have a flask app that generates a pre-signed URL to S3 and uploads a file into a bucket.
Code:

```
def create_presigned_post(bucket_name, object_name,
                          fields=None, conditions=None, expiration=3600):
    """Generate a presigned URL S3 POST request to upload a file

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param object_name: string
    :param fields: Dictionary of prefilled form fields
    :param conditions: List of conditions to include in the policy
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid
    :return: Dictionary with the following keys:
        url: URL to post to
        fields: Dictionary of form fields and values to submit with the POST
    :return: None if error.
    """

    # Generate a presigned S3 POST URL
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(bucket_name,
                                                     object_name,
                                                     Fields=fields,
                                                     Conditions=conditions,
                                                     ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None

    # The response contains the presigned URL and required fields
    return response
@app.route('/upload',methods=['post'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        diag_file = request.files['file']
        if diag_file:
                filename = secure_filename(diag_file.filename)
                diag_file.save(filename)
                result = create_presigned_post("bucket123", filename)
                # How another Python program can use the presigned URL to upload a file
                with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                    files = {'file': (filename, f)}
                    http_response = requests.post(result['url'], data=result['fields'], files=files)
                # If successful, returns HTTP status code 204
                print(result['url'])
                print(http_response.status_code)
                logging.info(f'File upload HTTP status code: {http_response.status_code}')
                # s3.upload_file(
                #     Bucket = BUCKET_NAME,
                #     Filename=filename,
                #     Key = filename
                # )
                msg = "Diag file Uploaded!"

    return render_template("file_upload_to_s3.html",msg =msg)
```

The file uploads fine with no errors.

When I go to access the file by copying the S3 URL and paste it into another tab in the same browser I get:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>CQNCGDS4YKCPDWQ6</RequestId>
<HostId>
LsJI1jBMUCeQpL4qjfqipmvYeCJ5TaS3ZoBwbmXMbbklWo5stWMdVtGI50Ib+XDciHerIm5AADw=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

How can I download this file from S3 via the browser?

Comment: " S3 URL" - this is the same URL you used for uploading?

Comment: @Marcin no. this is the url of the object in the S3 ... Looks like this: https://bucket123.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test.tgz

Answer (score 1):

The url `bucket123.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test.tgz`  will work only if the object is **public**. This requires either changing its ACL or setting up a bucket policy.

If you don't want to make it public, you have to create **S3 pre-signed URL**. So basically, what you tried to do last time, but this time it is for GET, not upload of the objects.

For boto3, the code is [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html#presigned-urls):

```
def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration=3600):
    """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param object_name: string
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid
    :return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
    """

    # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                            'Key': object_name},
                                                    ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None

    # The response contains the presigned URL
    return response
```